# Unsure if I should split my subclasses

Tags: java, arraylist, split, text-files, subclass

I have a text file that reads in information of various employees.
I've  created two array list that are based on the years of an Employee object. The Employee has two subclasses, Salesman and Executive. I'm wondering how I should split it by commas if there's two subclasses, since I can't call the super class

Here's the employee class

```
public class Employee 
{
private String name;
private double monthlySalary;

public Employee(String line)
{
    String[]split=line.split(",");
    name=split[0];
    monthlySalary=Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}



public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}



public double getMonthlySalary() {
    return monthlySalary;
}



public void setMonthlySalary(double monthlySalary) {
    this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
}



public double annualSalary()
{
    return monthlySalary*12;
}


public String toString()
{
    String str;
    str="Name: "+name;
    str+="\nMonthly Salary: "+monthlySalary;
    return str;
}
}
```

The Salesman class

```
public class Salesman extends Employee
{
private double annualSales;

public Salesman(String name, double monthlySalary, double annualSales)
{
    super(name,monthlySalary);
    this.annualSales=annualSales;
}



public double getAnnualSales() {
    return annualSales;
}



public void setAnnualSales(double annualSales) {
    this.annualSales = annualSales;
}



public double annualSalary()
{
    double commision=annualSales*0.02;
    if (commision>20000)
    {
        commision=20000;
    }
    double totalSalary=super.annualSalary()+commision;
    return totalSalary;
}


public String toString()
{
    return super.toString()+"\nAnnual Sales: "+annualSales;
}
}
```

The Executive class

```
public class Executive extends Employee
{
private double stockPrice;

public Executive(String name, double monthlySalary, double stockPrice)
{
    super(name,monthlySalary);
    this.stockPrice=stockPrice;
}


public double getStockPrice() {
    return stockPrice;
}


public void setStockPrice(double stockPrice) {
    this.stockPrice = stockPrice;
}


public double annualSalary()
{
    double bonus=0;
    if(stockPrice>50)
    {
        bonus=30000;
    }
    double totalSalary=super.annualSalary()+bonus;
    return totalSalary;
}


public String toString()
{
    return super.toString()+"\nStock Price: "+stockPrice;
}
}
```

And the driver class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class employeeDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input;
    Scanner readInput=null;
    Scanner readFile = null;

    try
    {
        readFile=new Scanner(new File("C:\\mywork\tester.txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("The file can't be opened");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    List<Employee> firstList= new ArrayList<>();
    List<Employee> secondList= new ArrayList<>();


    while(readFile.hasNextLine())
    {
      //To be inserted
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear for me, could you elaborate please?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm wondering if I should use the split method for all three classes, or only for the super class. I'm also wondering if I still need to call the super class for my subclass constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I with *split method* you mean something that parse the file, I think you should place this login in another class, that have nothing to do with Employee.

This could be something like ParseEmployeeFile or ScanEmpoyeeFile, with a method *parse()* or *scan()*.

This method should return a standard record, a List or a Map, depends on your needs.

From this record you should be able to create the proper Employee.

To do that, you need what is called a Factory class.

This is a class that contains the logic to create the proper Employee subclass object.

For example:

```
class EmployeeFactory {

    public static Employee create(Record record) {

        if (record.get("annualSales") != null) {
            return new Salesman(record.get("name"),
                                record.get("monthlySalary"),
                                record.get("annualSales"));
        }

        if (record.get("stockPrice") != null) {
            return new Executive(record.get("name"),
                                record.get("monthlySalary"),
                                record.get("stockPrice"));
        }


       return new Employee(record.get("name"),
                           record.get("monthlySalary"));
    }
}
```

This can be improved as needed.

Comment: The thing is that this is an assignment for a class, and we're required to write only four classes, and store the data in two arrays based on the year the employee joined

Comment: @Matt I very much doubt that your teacher will tell you that you did a bad job if you actually go an extra step.

Comment: @Matt no problem, use the Factory method, than instead of the class. You could put the method in the Employee superclass as a static method. And for the Parser part, you could implement this method in your main class. And the Record could be List or Map of course, don't need a specific type.

Comment: If I'm parsing the text file in my super class, wouldn't I need to initialize the annualSales and stockPrice variables in my super class? And if the parse method is static, does that mean my instance variables will be static as well?

Comment: @Matt sorry, I mean the parser method should be in your *employeeDriver* class. The factory method in *Employee* superclass. Even the method is static it returns an object instance, that is not.

Comment: public static List parse(String line)
 {
  String[]split=line.split(",");
  String name=split[0];
  Double monthlySalary=Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
  Double annualSales=Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
  Double stockPrice=Double.parseDouble(split[3]);
  
 }                                                                                                                Is this how my parser method should look?

Comment: Yes, looks ok. You just have return the list. The static is not necessary here, but it's ok. Just the factory method need to be static.

Comment: So I should add a line at the top of the parse method that creates a new Array List, then add a line at the bottom that returns it? Do I have to add each element that I parse?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the input text file contains lines and each of them consists of information of an employee concatenated with commas, like csv file.

In my opinion, you should not use `String#split()` in the Employee and its subclasses code. After reading file completed in success, then split every line into each attributes (like name and monthlySalary), and then pass them to constructors of Employee or its subclasses.

By clearly distinguishing getting information of the file with making Employee objects, Employee class becomes robuster. For example, please assume information to create Employee objects came from another format (like xml file)? You cannot cope with that easily if you call `String#split()` inside of Employee's constructor!